# html print hyperlink with unwanted extra link

Tags: html, css, printing

I am working on this website that has a printing problem, if I do a print, the hyperlinks got printed out twice: here is what I meant by twice

Html code: `<p>Urgent Care: <a href="tel:765-494-1700">765-494-1724</a>.</p>`

Print output:
Urgent Care: 765­494­1724 (tel:765­494­1700)

I ONLY NEED Urgent Care: 765-494-1724 (NOT tel:765­494­1700). But, I do need the hyperlink to be `<a href="tel:765-494-1700">` because this hyperlink needs to be used on cellphone, and when people click on it, it will auto driven them to the dial screen.

In my print.css file, I actually already try to fix this problem by doing:

```
a:link, a:visited  {
content: "";
}
```

But It did not work :( So I am hoping that I could get some ideas on this problem if possible. Thanks a million!!!

P.S.: Working on MAC OS, chrome, safari, firefox all NOT printing right...

Comment: Post the whole print.css file.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your print.css (and remove your `a:link, a:visited` rule)

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML:

```
Urgent Care: <a href="tel:765-494-1700"><span class="phonenumber">765-494-1724</span></a>
```

Your CSS:

```
@media print {
  a span.phonenumber{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

This will hide the text within the link, so it only shows the text of the link itself, which is the phone number (`tel:765-494-1700`).

Maybe you don't need to create a link, though, because most mobile browser will recognise any number as a phone number.

Alternatively, you can also make the phone number plain text (or a link with an empty href) and fill in the href using Javascript.

Comment: And now I read [here](http://designshack.net/articles/css/6-thinks-i-learned-about-print-stylesheets-from-html5-boilerplate/) that you actually need to make some effort to even show those links. Are you sure you don't have any CSS of other code to show this link in the first place?

Comment: Hey thx, this is getting there. I meant It does hide the text and the html page is fine, but it printed out (tel:765-494-1700) with parenthese, how could I get rid of the parenthese?

Comment: @LittleTalks: You shouldn't be adding unnecessary HTML markup just for the sake of visual representation. Use CSS only solutions where possible.

Answer (score -1):

What if you just made the link like this:

`<a href="tel:765-494-1700">.</a></p>`

Does that make it just show up once?

Comment: Probably, but then you will see only a period in the non-print version.

Comment: That would make the actual text cellphone number disappear on html page

Answer (score -1):

in your print css do like below :

```
@media print
  {
    a.no_print{display:none;}
    a.to_print{display:block;}
  }
```

in the regular css you do the reverse :

```
a.no_print{display:block;}
a.to_print{display:none;}
```

And your html :

```
<p>Urgent Care: <a href="tel:765-494-1700" class="no_print" >765-494-1724</a> <a class="to_print" >765-494-1724</a>.</p>
```

Comment: I followed your code, but it actually hide both text on html page and on the printing page...

Comment: you were probably missing `!important;` at the end of each line.

Comment: At least leave a comment for the -1 ??